# Can we conclude from that, that there is an homomorphism between the group $G$ and the group $(\mathbb{Z}_3,+)$?

Tags: group-theory, abstract-algebra

We have the third order group $G=\{1,g,x\}$, whose operation is the multiplication.

To calculate the multiplication table we do the following:

$1 \cdot 1=1, \ \ \ 1 \cdot g=g, \ \ \ 1 \cdot x=x$

$g \cdot 1=g$

$g \cdot g=g^2=\{1 (\text{ it cannot be 1 because the order of the group is } 3, \\ \text{ so it must be } g^m=1 \text{ where } 3 \mid m ) \text{ or } x \text{ or } g ( \text{ it cannot be } \\ \text{ because then } g=1 \text{ and then the group would contain only two elements})\}=x$

$g \cdot x=1 (\text{ because otherwise it would be } x=1 \text{ or } g=1)$

$x \cdot 1=x$

$x \cdot g=1 (\text{ because otherwise it would be } x=1 \text{ or } g=1)$

$x \cdot x=g (\text{ because otherwise it would be } x=1 \text{ or } x=g)$

Therefore $G=\{1,g, g^2\}$.

The multiplication table is the following:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
 \cdot & &1 & g & g^2 & \\ 
 & &- & - & - & \\ 
1 & | & 1 & g &g^2 \\ 
g & | & g &  g^2& 1\\ 
g^2 &|  & g^2 & 1 & g
\end{bmatrix}$$

The multiplication table is the same as the one of the group of the third roots of unity.

We know that there is a group homomorphism between the group of the $n$-th roots of unity and the group $(\mathbb{Z}_n,+)$.

Can we conclude from that, that there is an homomorphism between the group $G$ and the group $(\mathbb{Z}_3,+)$??

Comment: There is always at least one group homomorphism from $G$ to $H$, given by $f(g) = 1_H$. Do you mean to ask if there is an isomorphism?

Comment: Did you read the answer to your previous question?

Comment: @anon I meant $\mathbb{Z}_3$...

Answer (score 1):

By your explanation it seems to me that you have proved that your original group is a cyclic group.Now prove in general that every cyclic group $G$ of order n is isomorhic to $(\mathbb{Z}_n,+)$ b.Let $G=<a>$ define $f:G\to(\mathbb{Z}_n,+) $ as $a^{k}\to{k}$ $modn$ show that f is an isomorphism